# Resize one part of screen when keyboard appears

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to resize one part of screen when keyboard appears.

I want this:

Without keyboard :
[image]

When keyboard appear :
[image]

So I want just the ListView to resize and if I select EditText1 or EditText2 I want to see both. If a select ET1 I need to see ET2 too.

Rigth now I have this XAML but all of my screen is scroll up when keyboard appeard and when I select ET1, ET2 is behind keyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp">
        <ListView
            android:background="@drawable/border_shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:importantForAccessibility="auto"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:shadowColor="#00000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:shadowColor="#00000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google have made a real dog’s dinner of Keyboards in Android and have stubbornly refused to rectify it. They have refused to add callbacks for a change in keyboard state or a way to get the keyboard size. In addition, the way that they handle the resizing and panning of the visible screen is inconsistent and prone to bugs.
In your case, the ideal situation would be to have an event fired when the keyboard opens or closes, that contains the size of the keyboard. Try the following utility service I created. It's not perfect but it works, even in debug mode and with a hardware keyboard, and gives you the flexibility to to adjust things as you need.

```
public class KeyboardStatusService
{

    public delegate void KeyboardStatusChangeEventHandler(KeyboardStatusChangeEventArgs e);
    public event KeyboardStatusChangeEventHandler KeyboardStatusChangeEvent;

    private int _openHeightDelta = -1;
    private int _closedHeightDelta = 0;

    private InputMethodManager __imm = null;
    private InputMethodManager _imm
    {
        get
        {
            if (__imm == null || __imm.Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                __imm = BaseApplication.CurrentActivity?.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            return __imm;
        }
    }


    public KeyboardStatus Status { get; private set; } = KeyboardStatus.Closed;  // Default to closed when the app starts

    public bool Subscribed { get; private set; } = false;

    // Threshold used to remove false positives
    public int Threshold { get; set; } = 144;    

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        Subscribe(BaseApplication.CurrentActivity);
    }

    public void Subscribe(Activity activity)
    {
        if (!Subscribed)
        {
            var rootLayout = activity?.Window.DecorView; //.FindViewById(global::Android.Resource.Id.Content);
            if (rootLayout != null)
            {
                // Subscribe to ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout
                rootLayout.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += LayoutChangeDetected;
                Subscribed = true;  // so we only ever subscribe once
            }
        }
    }

    private async void LayoutChangeDetected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => { LayoutChangeDetected(); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


    private void LayoutChangeDetected()
    {
        var open = _imm.IsAcceptingText;
        if (Status == KeyboardStatus.Closed && open)  // was closed. now open
        {
            var rootLayout = BaseApplication.CurrentActivity.Window.DecorView;
            Rect r = new Rect();
            rootLayout.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            Rect r1 = new Rect();
            rootLayout.GetLocalVisibleRect(r1);
            var heightDelta = r1.Bottom - r.Bottom;

            // Double check (in case we have manually changed layouts in response to the keyboard opening and closing
            if (heightDelta > _closedHeightDelta + Threshold)  // may need to add padding here to account for other layout changes
            {
                if (_openHeightDelta == -1)
                    _openHeightDelta = heightDelta;
                Status = KeyboardStatus.Open;
                // Trigger the event
                KeyboardStatusChangeEvent?.Invoke(new KeyboardStatusChangeEventArgs(Status, _openHeightDelta));
            }

        }
        else if (Status == KeyboardStatus.Open)
        {
            if (!open)  // was open. now closed -  this handles when an action results in EditText losing focus and input ability
            {
                Status = KeyboardStatus.Closed;
                // Trigger the event
                KeyboardStatusChangeEvent?.Invoke(new KeyboardStatusChangeEventArgs(Status, _closedHeightDelta));
            }
            else
            {
                // some actions don't result in edit Text losing focus or input ability, such as keyboard dismiss button.
                // This may be limited to when a hardware keyboard is attached, such as when debugging
                var rootLayout = BaseApplication.CurrentActivity.Window.DecorView;
                Rect r = new Rect();
                rootLayout.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                Rect r1 = new Rect();
                rootLayout.GetLocalVisibleRect(r1);
                var heightDelta = r1.Bottom - r.Bottom;
                if  (heightDelta < _openHeightDelta - Threshold)  // may need to add padding here to account for other layout changes
                {
                    _closedHeightDelta = heightDelta;
                    Status = KeyboardStatus.Closed;
                    // Trigger the event
                    KeyboardStatusChangeEvent?.Invoke(new KeyboardStatusChangeEventArgs(Status, _closedHeightDelta));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        Unsubscribe(BaseApplication.CurrentActivity);
    }
    public void Unsubscribe(Activity activity)
    {
        var rootLayout = activity?.Window.DecorView; //.FindViewById(global::Android.Resource.Id.Content);
        if (rootLayout != null)
        {
            rootLayout.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout -= LayoutChangeDetected;  // Don't need to check for subscribed as wont cause an issue
            Subscribed = false;
        }
    }


    public static void DismissKeyboard(Activity activity, View view)
    {
        if (view == null)
            view = new View(activity);
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        iMM.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        view.ClearFocus();
    }
    public static void DismissKeyboard(Context ctx, View view)
    {
        if (view == null)
            view = new View(ctx);
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)ctx.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        iMM.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        view.ClearFocus();
    }
    public static void DismissKeyboard(Context ctx, Fragment fragment)
    {
        var view = fragment.View.RootView;
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)ctx.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        iMM.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        view.ClearFocus();
    }
    public static void DismissKeyboard(Context ctx, global::Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment)
    {
        var view = fragment.View.RootView;
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)ctx.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        iMM.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        view.ClearFocus();
    }
    public static void DismissKeyboard(Fragment fragment)
    {
        var view = fragment.View.RootView;
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)fragment.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        iMM.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        view.ClearFocus();
    }
    public static void DismissKeyboard(global::Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment)
    {
        var view = fragment.View.RootView;
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)fragment.Activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        iMM.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        view.ClearFocus();
    }
    public static void DismissKeyboard(Activity activity)
    {
        var view = activity.FindViewById(global::Android.Resource.Id.Content).RootView;
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        iMM.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        view.ClearFocus();
    }
    public static void ToggleKeyboard(Activity activity)
    {
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        iMM.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Implicit, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
    }
    public static void ShowKeyboard(Activity activity, View view, bool forced = false)
    {
        if (view == null)
            view = new View(activity);
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        if (forced)
            iMM.ShowSoftInput(view, ShowFlags.Forced);
        else
            iMM.ShowSoftInput(view, ShowFlags.Implicit);
    }
    public static void ShowKeyboard(Context ctx, View view, bool forced = false)
    {
        if (view == null)
            view = new View(ctx);
        InputMethodManager iMM = (InputMethodManager)ctx.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        if (forced)
            iMM.ShowSoftInput(view, ShowFlags.Forced);
        else
            iMM.ShowSoftInput(view, ShowFlags.Implicit);
    }

}

public enum KeyboardStatus
{
    Closed,
    Open,
    Unknown
}

public class KeyboardStatusChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public KeyboardStatus Status { get; private set; } = KeyboardStatus.Unknown;
    public int VisibleHeightToDecorHeightDelta { get; private set; } = -1;
    public KeyboardStatusChangeEventArgs(KeyboardStatus status, int visibleHeightToDecorHeightDelta)
    {
        Status = status;
        VisibleHeightToDecorHeightDelta = visibleHeightToDecorHeightDelta;
    }
}
```

Then subscribe/unsubscribe to it in your activities like so:

```
private KeyboardStatusService KeyboardStatus { get; } = new KeyboardStatusService();
private int _keyboardHeight;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    KeyboardStatus.Subscribe(this);
    KeyboardStatus.KeyboardStatusChangeEvent += OnKeyboardStatusChanged;
    ...........
}

protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    KeyboardStatus.KeyboardStatusChangeEvent -= OnKeyboardStatusChanged;
    KeyboardStatus.Unsubscribe(this);
    ........
}

private void OnKeyboardStatusChanged(KeyboardStatusChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var keyboardStatus = e.Status;
    if (keyboardStatus == KeyboardStatus.Open)
    {
        var heightDelta = e.VisibleHeightToDecorHeightDelta;
        // need to adjust keyboard height calculation based upon the prescribed adjustment for the Activity set as  WindowSoftInputMode
        // the presence of a toolbar and.or status bar
        _keyboardHeight = heightDelta - YourToolBarHeight - YourStatusBarHeight;

        // ADJUST THE HEIGHT OF YOUR VIEW HERE

    }
    else
    {
        // ADJUST THE HEIGHT OF YOUR VIEW HERE
    }
}
```

Here is BaseApplication:

```
public partial class BaseApplication: Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public int NumberActivitiesActive { get; protected set; }

    public static ApplicationState ApplicationState { get; protected set; } = ApplicationState.NotRunning;

    public static DateTime AppEnteredTime { get; protected set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
    public static DateTime AppLeftTime { get; protected set; } = DateTime.MinValue;

    public static double TimeInAppMs
    {
        get
        {
            if (AppLeftTime == DateTime.MinValue)
                return DateTime.Now.Subtract(AppEnteredTime).TotalMilliseconds;
            else
                return AppLeftTime.Subtract(AppEnteredTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        }
    }


    public static Activity CurrentActivity { get; private set; }


    // Used to store activities to be excluded from counts, such as Activities used to handle notifications in response to push notifications
    public static List<string> ExcludedActivities { get; } = new List<string>();

    public static void RegisterExcludedActivity(string activityName)
    {
        if (!ExcludedActivities.Contains(activityName))
            ExcludedActivities.Add(activityName);
    }
    public static void UnregisterExcludedActivity(string activityName)
    {
        ExcludedActivities.Remove(activityName);
    }


    public BaseApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }


    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ApplicationState = ApplicationState.NotRunning;
    }

    public override void OnTerminate()
    {
        base.OnTerminate();
        UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ApplicationState = ApplicationState.NotRunning;
    }


    public virtual void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CurrentActivity = activity;
    }

    public virtual void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) // Exclude this activity because it only relates to a notification created in response to a  push notification
    {
        if (!ExcludedActivities.Contains(activity.LocalClassName) && NumberActivitiesActive <= 0)
            ApplicationState = ApplicationState.NotRunning;
    }

    public virtual void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
    {
        CurrentActivity = activity;
    }

    public virtual void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
    {
    }

    public virtual void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
    {
        CurrentActivity = activity;
        if (!ExcludedActivities.Contains(activity.LocalClassName))
        {
            if (NumberActivitiesActive == 0)
            {
                AppEnteredTime = DateTime.Now;
                ApplicationState = ApplicationState.Foreground;
            }
            NumberActivitiesActive++;
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
    {
        if (!ExcludedActivities.Contains(activity.LocalClassName))
        {
            NumberActivitiesActive--;
            if (NumberActivitiesActive == 0)
            {
                AppLeftTime = DateTime.Now;
                if (activity.IsFinishing)
                    ApplicationState = ApplicationState.NotRunning;
                else
                    ApplicationState = ApplicationState.Background;
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum ApplicationState
{
    Background,
    Foreground,
    NotRunning,
    Unknown
}
```

To use base Application you need to declare a MainApplication that inherits from Base Application in your project, and give it the [Application] annotation like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    [Application(Debuggable = true)]
#else
    [Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif
    public partial class MainApplication : BaseApplication
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm with a error in BaseApplication. I need some import?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that utility class - have now added, it. Have also updated the Keyboard status service, so it handles the situation where IMM.IsAcceptingText returns true when an activity starts.